# Is it possible to point tensorflow to a specific version of CUDA after tensorflow has been installed?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to run tensorflow on a cuda machine over the cloud where I do not have sudo privileges.

I installed tensorflow in a virtualenv but I am not able to point it towards a specific cuda version. Can this be only done when installing from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Ubuntu systems I use (to be executed in the same terminal as the one in which you run TensorFlow):

```
# CUDA 7.5:
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# CUDA 8.0:
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You may also want to point to CuDNN and CNMeM:

```
# CuDNN:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch1/francky/cudnn/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=/scratch1/francky/cudnn/cuda/include:$CPATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch1/francky/cudnn/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# CNMeM:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch1/francky/cudnn/cnmem/build:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=/scratch1/francky/cudnn/cnmem/include:$CPATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch1/francky/cudnn/cnmem/build:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

FYI: [Is there any point in using CNMeM when running TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42396992/395857)

Comment: is there any way this can be set to run automatically when the virtualenv is launched? just like placing it in .bashrc would do...

Answer (score 0):

Usually `CUDA_HOME` allows to solve such kind of issues. As for TensorFlow up to 0.12, the [homepage](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup) gives detailed information.

Version 1.0 is available now, and the documentation has been updated (not re-read at this point), so there might be extra information there if you switched.

Comment: I tried setting the CUDA_HOME variable but it did not work. I have multiple cuda versions installed. I need to point it to version 8.