# Is there any point in using CNMeM when running TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

The [CNMeM library](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cnmem) is a "simple library to help the Deep Learning frameworks manage CUDA memory."

[CNMeM has been reported to give some interesting speed improvements](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/13381/843), and is supported by Theano, Torch, and Caffe. However, TensorFlow  preallocates GPU memory when starting a session, unlike Theano, Torch, and Caffe.

Does using CNMeM when running a TensorFlow-based program help (e.g., reduce the running time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Tensorflow has its own GPU memory management. Indeed it takes upfront the whole GPU memory regardless of the size of your problem.